# Launching chromedriver from cron job

Tags: macos, cron, selenium-chromedriver

Running a Mac with OSX Sierra, I have some robot framework scripts that use the chromerdriver. The scripts are all called from one shell script which runs fine when run manually, but when running the shell script from a cron job the error below is returned:

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

I have confirmed the chromedriver location (/usr/local/bin) is in my Path and has 777 permissions. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you absolutely certain it is on the path _of the user associated with the cron job_? Try having the script run by cron print out its path before starting robot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to Edit your Path and add *chromedriver* to Python folder?

Because I had the same problem.
Now my Path looks like

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Python/2.7/:/Users/jorma

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately that did not fix it. I placed a copy of the chromedriver into /Library/Python/2.7/ and added that to my Path...

Comment: echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Python/2.7:/Users/jorma

Still receiving the same error. I also double clicked the chromedriver executable to allow/confirm it can run. Restarted my Mac, but still receiving same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by putting my path in the top of my shell script...

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Python‌​/2.7:/Users/jorma